# Run script on VPN up with reference to existing user

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn, udev

I've been scratching my head on this for a day or so now, and have tried a number of different ways of getting this working but seem fundamentally stuck. I want to run a simple Python script when a user connects to the VPN, but the script needs to be able to receive the username of the person who is activated the connection (ie listing all logged-in users may not work as only one of those is currently active).

I've looked at udev rules, /etc/network/if-up.d, and etc/NetworkManager/dispatch.d and I can't work out how to get any of these working while also passing the current user to them.

/etc/udev/rules simply doesn't seem to run on VPN up, and if-up.d/dispatcher.d both run as root with no apparent way to get that username.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Have you checked if there is any output from `udevadm monitor` when  VPN get up?